# problems with the leaderboard discord.py

Tags: discord.py

The leaderboard shows the same username even if they are different users in case they have the same value.
I don't know how to solve it but when in the code I ask to resist a variable it gives me only 3 elements and not 4 even if 4 come out.
[image]

code:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["lb"])
async def leaderboard(ctx,x = 10):
    leader_board = {}
    total = []
    for user in economy_system:
        name = int(user)
        total_amount = economy_system[user]["wallet"] + economy_system[user]["bank"]
        leader_board[total_amount] = name
        total.append(total_amount)
    print(leader_board)
    total = sorted(total,reverse=True)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = f"Top {x} Richest People",
        description = "This is decided on the basis of raw money in the bank and wallet",
        color = 0x003399
    )
    index = 1
    for amt in total:
        id_ = leader_board[amt]
        member = client.get_user(id_)
        name = member.name
        print(name)
        embed.add_field(
            name = f"{index}. {name}",
            value = f"{amt}",
            inline = False
        )
        if index == x:
            break
        else:
            index += 1

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

print resists this:

```
{100: 523967502665908227, 350: 554617490806800387, 1100: 350886488235311126}
Padre Mapper
Flore (Orsolinismo)
Aetna
Aetna
```

In theory there should also be `100: 488826524791734275` (i.e. my user id) but it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from this line:

```py
leader_board[total_amount] = name
```

If `total_amount` is already a key (eg. two users have the same amount of money), it will replace the previous value (which was a user ID) and replace it with another user ID. In this situation, if multiple users have the same amount of money, only one will be saved in `leader_board`.

Then, you have this line:

```py
total.append(total_amount)
```

In this case, if two users have the same amount of money, you would just have two identical values, which is normal but, considering the problem above, this will create a shift.

Let's say you have ten users with two of them who have the same amount of money. `leader_board` will only contain 9 items whereas `total` will contain 10 values. That's the reason why you have two of the same name in your message.

To solve the problem:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["lb"])
async def leaderboard(ctx, x=10):
    d = {user_id: info["wallet"] + info["bank"] for user_id, info in economy_system.items()}
    leaderboard = {user_id: amount for user_id, amount in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = f"Top {x} Richest People",
        description = "This is decided on the basis of raw money in the bank and wallet",
        color = 0x003399
    )

    for index, infos in enumerate(leaderboard.items()):
        user_id, amount = infos
        member = client.get_user(user_id)
        embed.add_field(
            name = f"{index}. {member.display_name}",
            value = f"{amount}",
            inline = False
        )

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

If I guessed right and your dictionnary is organized like this, it should work:

```py
economy_system = {
    user_id: {"bank": x, "wallet": y}
}
```

Comment: I wrote a comment telling about my problem but being all the time trying to solve it, I did it! In practice it did not work for me because it could not see the user id as an integer and did not recognize items (it had to be items). I wanted to ask you something if it is possible to have an answer that is if it is possible to have the positions from the eleventh to the 20 by doing "lb 2" for example?